# Change checked radio button color in Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to change checked RadioButton color. But I don't know the way to change it.

```
    <RadioButton
  android:id="@+id/type_cambodia"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:button="@null"
  android:drawablePadding="20dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_margin"
  android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
  android:text="@string/type_goal_khmer_kh"/>
```

Comment: create a style and apply it as theme in radiobutton

Comment: add this to radio button  app:buttonTint="@color/primary"